Imagenes con React
Muy buenas tardes.
Quisiera pedir de su apoyo con un tema que tengo con un proyecto en react, apenas estoy empezando y me surgio un detalle con el apartado de la etiqueta img, el proyecto lo realize con Vite y le di la opcion de JavaScript en la opcion de configuracion, el detalle que tengo con la imagen es que al correrla en el servidor local osea mi equipo si puedo visualizar bien las imagenes con la ruta y todo, pero al hacer el deploy del sitio en Vercel no se muestran las imagenes.
este es mi codigo
import '../styles/Banner.css'

function Banner() {
    return (
        <div className="w-full h-full">
            <div className="w-auto h-auto mx-4 rounded-lg bg-[url('/src/img/fondo.webp')] bg-cover p-4
            grid justify-center justify-items-center
            md:flex md:justify-around
            ">
                <img className="w-60 h-72 rounded-full md:w-80 md:h-96" src="../../src/img/Use.webp" alt="Foto" />
                <div className="mt-8 grid justify-center justify-items-center md:mt-0 md:justify-stretch md:content-center">
                    <p className="banner-text uno">Hola!</p>
                    <p className="banner-text dos">Mundo</p>
                    <h1 className="banner-text tres uppercase">support</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Banner

Lo curioso es que en el apartado de la imagen que es fondo.webp si carga la imagen en vercel y si coloco la misma ruta en el apartado de img no se muestra la imagen, solo con el de fondo.webp si funciona pero en la etiqueta img que tiene el Use.webp no
Me podrian apoyar con esta duda que tengo, excelente dia.

https://caniuse.com/?search=webp

Hola, porqué no usas la misma sintaxis para la imagen que no te está funcionando? O sea... Una la tienes como absoluta (la que te funciona) y la otra como relativa (y no te funciona)... Puedes actualizar con una captura de los directorios del proyecto desde este archivo hasta la imagen? Un saludo!

Es que lo curioso es que si coloco esta ruta bg-[url('/src/img/fondo.webp')] que es de la etiqueta div si funciona bien la ruta, si me muestra la imagen sin problemas, pero si me voy a la etiqueta img que es en teoria donde tengo cada imagen en su propiedad de SRC con el path de src="../../src/img/Use.webp" no me muestra nada, intente replicar dejando los elementos de img en su SRC con el mismo del div y aun asi no me muestra las imagenes, solo el div si se muestra.
Intente tanto dejarlo en la carpeta de Public y tambien en el SRC y aun asi no funciona, dejo como tengo mis carpetas hechas o como tengo mi rutas, tambien lo que he probado es mover la carpeta de IMG tanto a la PUBLIC como a la SRC y aun asi no hay cambios en mostrar la imagen
